# How to perform repeated regression in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an excel file that contains 5 columns and 48 rows (water demand, population and rainfall data for four years (1997-2000) of each month)

```
Year  Month  Water_Demand Population Rainfall  
1997   1        355        4500        25  
1997   2        375        5000        20  
1997   3        320        5200        21  
.............% rest of the month data of year 1997.  
1997  12        380        6000        24  
1998   1        390        6500        23  
1998   2        370        6700        20  
............. % rest of the month data of year 1998  
1998  12        400        6900        19  
1999   1  
1999   2  
.............% rest of the month data of year 1997 and 2000  
2000   12       390        7000        20
```

i want to do the multiple linear regression in MATLAB. Here dependent variable is water demand and independent variable is population and rainfall. I have written the code for this for all the 48 rows

```
A1=data(:,3);
A2=data(:,4);
A3=data(:,5);
x=[ones(size(A1)),A2,A3];
y=A1;
b=regress(y,x);
yfit=b(1)+b(2).*A2+b(3).*A3;
```

Now I want to do the repetition. First, I want to exclude the row number 1 (i.e. exclude year 1997, month 1 data) and do the regression with rest of the 47 rows data. Then I want to exclude row number 2, and do the regression with data of row number 1 and row 3-48. Then I want exclude row number 3 and do the regression with data of row number 1-2 and row 4-48. There is alway 47 row data point as I exclude one row in each run. Finally, I want to get a table of regression coefficient and yfit of each run.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way I can think of is creating a for loop and a temporary "under test" matrix that is exactly the matrix you have without the line you want to exclude, like this

```
C = zeros(3,number_of_lines);
for n = 1:number_of_lines
  under_test = data;
  % this excludes the nth line of the matrix
  under_test(n,:) = [];
  B1=under_test(:,3); 
  B2=under_test(:,4); 
  B3=under_test(:,5); 
  x1=[ones(size(B1)),B2,B3]; 
  y1=B1; 
  C(:,n)=regress(y1,x1);
end
```

I'm sure you can optimize this by using some of the matlab functions that operate on vectors, without using the for loop. But I think for only 48 lines it should be fast enough.

Comment: +1 for occam's razor.  Only kill yourself optimizing if performance is a problem.

Comment: Thanks Castilho. But when i run the code, it exclude only 48th row, gives result for 3*1 matrix for coefficient, but i want to get the matrix of 3*48 of coefficeint for all the 48 run . here is the code 'for n = 1:48 under_test = data; under_test(n,:) = []; B1=under_test(:,3); B2=under_test(:,4); B3=under_test(:,5); x1=[ones(size(B1)),B2,B3]; y1=B1; C=regress(y1,x1); end'

Comment: The for loop repeats the code written inside it. If you want to store all the values, you have to create a matrix the right size and save each iteration result on a different line. I've edited the code above to do just that. :)